# Combine different elements of a list in a dataframe using apply

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, cbind

I do have a main `List` containing sub-lists also containing elements. I would like to make a dataframe by combining the eighth element of each sub-list from the main `List`.

If I write this manually that's working:

```
DF <- cbind(List[[1]][[8]],List[[2]][[8]], ... List[[n]][[8]])
```

That's working, the result is the wanted dataframe. But I have a lot of sub-list within the main list and the lenght of the main List is not always the same. So, it is not efficient to write it manually.

I try this :

```
DF <- lapply(1:length(List), function(i) cbind(List[[i]][[8]]))
```

But the result is a list of lenght(List) containing indeed the eighth element of each sub-list but not the wanted dataframe. How can a obtain a dataframe and not another list ?

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind, lapply(List, \`[[\`, 8))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(1:length(List), function(i) cbind(List[[i]][[8]])))
```

Comment: The output of your code is one variable containing the concatenation of each eighth elements. I would like to obtain one variable(one column) for each element. Thanks for your time

Comment: Okay, here is what I need `do.call(cbind, lapply(1:length(List), function(i) cbind(List[[i]][[8]])))` Just have to convert it from a matrix to a df then. Thank you very much